# upload any type of file from sd card to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I want to fetch any type of file from mobile and I want to upload it to server.Using http://www.coderefer.com/android-upload-file-to-server I could upload files from internal storage but its not possible from sd card.How can I do this?

Comment: That should not make any difference. What are you doing wrong?

Comment: @greenapps selectedFilePath is null while selecting from SD card. But I am getting data for selectedFileUri.

Comment: You should do away with this FilePath class. Use `selectedFileUri` to open an `InputStream`. You do not need a `FileInputStream` for a file path.

Comment: @greenapps Ok. I will try with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
```

Change that to:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedFileUri);
```

Then read from the stream as you did before.

And do away with that `FilePath` class completely. Very bad code!